# 64 bit java is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java

Tags: installation, java, 64-bit, jre

I am trying to install JRE 8 64 bit on windows server 2012 r2 but it is getting installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java.

How do I checked: click on windows=>java=>right click=> location =>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java

I  need to install it as 64 bit.

JRE version is jdk-8u211-windows-x64

Can you please help me to install x64 bit JRE in right folder ?

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: It doesn't matter what folder Java gets installed in. Program Files (x86) and Program Files are different folders to help you as an admin/user differentiate between the two types of applications/installations. It really doesn't matter if a 64-bit program gets installed in the x86 folder, to my knowledge. If you really, really need to get it into x64 Program Files though, I suppose you could move the dependencies manually and then change the HOME (or whatever the variable for the home path in Java is - I haven't worked with Java in a while) variable after the fact.

Comment: You can choose the target directory when you install it ...